# Preprocessing vs Linking

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, preprocessor-directive

Everywhere I look for what a linker actually does (besides relocation, which some seem to put under "loading") people give examples of two (say) C modules which call functions from each other.

As far as I understand , this should be taken care of by preprocessing (#include etc). I can understand that if I want to assemble two modules at different times I would need to link them later. But when I use say gcc, it directly outputs the executable , so in this context I don't really see the point of linking except when the preprocessing (which will be recursive I'd guess) final hits object code.

Note : I'm referring to static linking here. I can see the point when it comes to dynamic linking.

Comment: First compile code to object files, then you can link them later so you won't have to recompile all whenever you build (could take a while or large projects).

Comment: #include is used to include declarations, not actual code. A header file normally includes no executable code (at least in C).

Comment: `gcc` is a tool-driver that invokes the C compiler (`cc1`) to do compiling
and invokes the linker (`ld`) to do linking. That's why you might imagine
that it "directly outputs the executable" without linking. It doesn't.
You can instruct `gcc` *not* to call the linker by passing it the `-c`
option. Try to build a program that way.

Comment: Search for the free book "linkers and loaders". Read it, it has better and better illustrated examples than I can reproduce here.

Comment: @Majora320 Alright that makes sense! @ rici I'm probably wrong about what #include does, but what I meant was, why not simply append all the files together and then compile it? Majora320 's comment answers that pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

gcc is using a lot of tools to create the executable, the compiler is one of them and so is the linker, preprocessor etc, to see what it's actually doing pass it the `-v` option. If you want to see the intermediate files use `-save-temps` ie once you've created the files below try this...

```
gcc-5 -save-temps -v -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic-errors main.c foo.c
```

If you look in your directory you'll see several extra files...

```
a.out // Executable when no name is specified
foo.c // original foo.c
foo.h // original foo.h
foo.i // Preprocessed ouput of foo.c and foo.h
foo.o // foo Object file
foo.s // foo assembler
main.c // original main.c
main.i // main preprocessed
main.o // main object file
main.s // main assembler
```

If you look in `main.i` you'll notice that it contains this

```
# 1 "foo.h" 1


int foo(int i);
```

but it doesn't know what the function foo actually does. That's all in `foo.i`. This also means that when the object files are created `main.o` knows it needs a `foo` function. Connecting symbol `foo` in main.o with the `foo` in foo.o is what the linker is doing.

Here's an example, create the following three files

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
int foo(int i); 
#endif
```

**foo.c**

```
#include "foo.h"
int foo(int i) {
  return i - 1729;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", foo(1));
  return 0;
}
```

Create their Object files ie not the executable as follows, note I've added the verbose flags to this..

```
gcc-5 -v -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic-errors main.c foo.c -c
```

If you had used the `-o` flag you would see the actual linker command that gcc called to link the objects into an executable ie

```
gcc-5 -v -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic-errors main.c foo.c -o fooer
```

At this point you will find two object files in your directory. You can create the executable using ld as follows (note this is mac specific, use the output from gcc -v to find the correct command for your machine).

```
ld -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.11.3 -lSystem main.o foo.o -o fooer
```